# Escaping in insert statement

Tags: mysql

How do I escape commas in mysql insert statements?

```
mysql> create table test.todel (name varchar(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert into test.todel values ('mcdonald's pizza');
    '> ';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's pizza');
'' at line 1

mysql> select  * from test.todel;
Empty set (0.02 sec)
```

I can escape the single comma, but that is not an option because I am using pretty complex shell script for inserting data.

```
mysql> insert into test.todel values ('mcdonald''s pizza');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test.todel;
+------------------+
| name             |
+------------------+
| mcdonald's pizza | 
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql_real_escape_string to scape it safely.

your way is not secured BTW.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_real_escape_string.asp

Comment: Please do not link to w3schools when you can [link to the official manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). [w3schools is known to be flawed](http://w3fools.com)